# keyword search in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using enhanced search moudle in DNN( http://dnnsearchenhanced.codeplex.com/ ). The DNN search is not working as expected after installing your module. I have made the following configurations

Login as Host
-Go to the Host menu and select Search Admin
-Fill in the blanks - max word length, min word length,
-Put checks in both boxes to include common words and numbers.
-Press Update.
-Press Re-Indexed Content 
- Then installed the module
-Press Re-Indexed Content  again

It is unable to search Title,Keywords and PageName.

Do i have to perform some sort of settings?

Note: Using DNN 6.2 Community Edition using included Search modules.

Thankx

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any search results? I would recommend checking the Host/Schedule page and the Search Indexer job's history to see if it is running, and if there are any errors being thrown.

Comment: any follow up to your question and my response?